# PyQt - Use QPushButton label as argument for function and link all the pushButton to one function

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, maya

I am currently working on a maya script for renaming referenced nodes. As you can see there is several pushButtons.
[Actual WIP interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvJIV.png)

I initialize the interface (I have an .ui file separately)

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connectSignalsSlots()
```

Then I would like to use a list to create loop for connecting button to the renaming function.
First question, should the list use string o variables are corrects?

And the most important one, how can I link the label for each pushButton in the list to the suffix arg in the rename function.

Here is the exemple I have to explain my purpose. (I know the script shouldn't work at this state. I just totally  don't know how to make this label link because I am not familiar with functions arguments and it is the thing I would like to solve)

```
        suffixButtons = [grpSuffix_pushButton, setSuffix_pushButton]
        for button in suffixButtons:
            self.button.clicked.connect(self.QuickSuffix)

    def QuickSuffix(self, suffix):
        if suffix == "_GRP":
            selection = pm.ls(selection=True, excludeType="reference")
        else:
            selection = pm.ls(selection=True, referencedNodes=True)

        for asset in selection :
            pm.rename(asset, suffix)
```

Thank you so much for your help and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can add arguments to your connected function with a lambda expression like so and then sent the label of your button to the function.
**Edit**: as musicamante mentioned in the comments my old solution would always caputre the last button.

```
for button in suffixButtons:
    button.clicked.connect(lambda _, button=button: self.QuickSuffix(button.text()))
```

I also think you should create the list like so `[self.grpSuffix_pushButton,...]` and remove the self in your for loop.

Comment: This won't work correctly: lambdas evaluate the expression only when executed, so `button.text()` will **always** refer to the last button in the for loop. The proper syntax should be `button.clicked.connect(lambda _, button=button: self.QuickSuffix(button.text()))`.